# Dynamic identifier with macros

Tags: elixir, absinthe

I'm using macros and I want to pass a dynamic identifier to an Absinthe macro `enum`, wanting to generate different `enum`s with a set list. Everything is inside a `for` comprehension.

I've read that `Kernel.apply/3` does not work on macros.

1. I've also tried:

```
   for name <- [:hello, :world] do
       enum  unquote(name) do
          value(:approved)
       end  
   end
```

Getting as a result:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   :erlang.atom_to_binary({:unquote, [line: 36], [{:name, [line: 36], nil}]}, :utf8)
```

2. I also tried without the unquote:

```
   for name <- [:hello, :world] do
      enum name do
        value(:approved)
      end
   end
```

And get:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   :erlang.atom_to_binary({:name, [line: 36], nil}, :utf8)
```

It seems that I can't unquote anything that I pass as the identifier of the macro `enum`. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. The problem is `enum` assumes the first argument is an atom.

```
defmodule MacroHelper do

  defmacro enum_wrapper(names, do: block) do
    for name <- names do
      quote do
        enum unquote(name), do: unquote(block)
      end
    end
  end

end

defmodule AbsDemo do

  use Absinthe.Schema.Notation
  import MacroHelper

  enum_wrapper [:hello, :world] do
    value :approved
  end

end
```